# how to solve the following oracle error invalid number

Tags: sql, database

i want to ask you when i execute the following sql statement

```
 SELECT account_identifier,least(to_number(part_1)),least (to_number(part_2)) FROM TEST5 ;
```

i get the following error

```
   ORA-01722: invalid number
   01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
   *Cause:    
   *Action:
```

you should know that when i execute the following sql statement

```
  SELECT account_identifier,to_number(part_1),to_number(part_2) FROM TEST5 ;
```

it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Most likely your part_1 column, or part_2 column, contains a null, or a string value.

Try the following to discover the row that causes this issue:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST5 WHERE part_1 IS NULL or part_2 IS NULL;
```

If NULL is your issue perhaps you could solve with the following:

```
SELECT account_identifier,least(to_number(part_1)),least (to_number(part_2)) FROM TEST5 WHERE part_1 IS NOT NULL and part_2 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: i want to ask you if it is contain a null value it will cause an error

Comment: yes it will cause an error because least function does not know what to do with NULL so it gets confused and cries to itself.

Comment: but when i tried min function i get the same error so does min function does not know how to deal with null values